# C# - Searching for sequences in arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, search

I have some arrays filled with 1 and 0. Is there any easy way to find, for example, 10 fields next to each other with value 1?

Something like: if (array[i ... i+10] = 1) -> do some stuff?

I know that I can use `for` to do it, but I have a huge multiple array and this will by very helpful.

Comment: If you want to have a fast lookup time without looping through, perhaps encode the information into your array from the get-go. Instead of storing your array with `1` and `0`, store it as a set of `Sequence` objects that have properties like `Value` (which would store `1` or `0`) and `Length` (which would indicate how many of that value is duplicated in a row). Then it would be much faster to jump through your array, one full sequence at a time. Can even put those sequences into an ordered lookup table of sorts (perhaps by `Length`).

Answer (score 7):

You can do this pretty easily with a for loop:

```
int c = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
{
    c = (myArray[i] == 1) ? c + 1 : 0;
    if (c >= 10)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Here's another way using Linq:

```
var indexes =
    from i in Enumerable.Range(0, myArray.Length - 10)
    where myArray.Skip(i).Take(10).All(x => x == 1)
    select i;
foreach(var i in indexes)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

This will return all indexes of `myArray` where the element at that index and the elements next 9 indexes are all equal to 1. However, this method is somewhat less efficient than the simple for-loop because it potentially checks each item more than once.

If you prefer fluent syntax:

```
var indexes = Enumerable.Range(0, myArray.Length - 10)
                        .Where(i => myArray.Skip(i).Take(10).All(x => x == 1));
foreach(var i in indexes)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Hi. it was a nice explanation. But, I've a doubt can you clarify ?I assume, The array has 12 items then range took 2(12-10) items. In where you put variable 'i' in skip, so i guess the value of 'i' was 1 and 2. How would it reaches 10th position ? Sorry, if it's very basic.

Comment: @RameshMuthiah It wouldn't. In the Linq solution, I only consider `i` in `[0, length-10]`. But it then tests `i` and the next 9 elements, so every element get's checked (at least once).

Comment: int[] value = new int[] {10,20,31,40,51,60,1,0,1,1,122,100,12,10,11};

            var result = from i in Enumerable.Range(0, value.Length - 10)
                         where value.Skip(i).Take(10).All(X => X == X)
                         select value[i];

Comment: Still i'm not clear. In that above sample, which returns only 5 values. why shouldn't return 10 results among 15 inputs ?

Comment: Finally, I understood The 'i' was 0 to 4. Then first iteration it skips 0, then next 1 and upto 4. Then, Finally it was reaming 5 values, which was a resultset. Thanks

Comment: @RameshMuthiah Well kind of backwards. It only considers the first 5 cases (`length-10`) but because of your lambda (`X => X == X`) all of those cases return true. So the result set is the value at the first 5 indexes. If you use my original code (`select i`) I think the behavior will be a bit more clear (result = `[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]`)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, you want to do something called pattern matching.

There are many algorithms out there. A first starting point is [this page here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm)

From the algorithms the Turbo-Boyer-Moore is one that is performing best.

But you can also handle that problem with a data structure, like a suffix tree:
[see this article on suffix trees (or simply called Trie)](http://marknelson.us/1996/08/01/suffix-trees/)

Here is an implementation of the Boyer-Moore algorithm [Codeproject article on Boyer-Moore](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12781/Boyer-Moore-and-related-exact-string-matching-algo)